# ASP.NET Publishing with Entity Framework

Tags: c#, asp.net

How to publish an ASP.NET C# Website with Entity Framework?

Comment: Carlo welcome to StackOverflow, please read [faq] and [ask]

Comment: Read these articles: [`Deploying Your Site Using Visual Studio`](http://www.asp.net/web-forms/tutorials/deployment/deploying-web-site-projects/deploying-your-site-using-visual-studio-cs) [`How to Deploy ASP.NET Web Application`](http://www.beansoftware.com/ASP.NET-Tutorials/Deploy-ASP.NET.aspx)